# SQL sort by number in column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 id|  name    |   created_at
    —-----------------------------
  1 | name 1  | 2017-05-20 
  2 | name 2  | 2017-05-22 
  3 | name 66  | 2017-05-24 
  4 | name 44  | 2017-05-25
```

i have a table Orders

I have to sort it by number in name column

like

```
id|  name    |   created_at
        —-----------------------------
      1 | name 66  | 2017-05-20 
      2 | name 44  | 2017-05-22 
      3 | name 2  | 2017-05-24 
      4 | name 1  | 2017-05-25
```

I have tried `SELECT * FROM Orders ORDER BY name DESC;` but no luck;

how i can do it?

Comment: You have to order by the extracted number part.

Comment: Is the name format guaranteed to be name,space,number?

Comment: @P.Salmon  i think yes. there is any difference in format for sql query in my case?

Answer (score 1):

If all the names are in the format `name, space, number` you can use this query. The [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) extracts the characters from the last space to the end and they are then [`CAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) as an unsigned integer, which allows them to be sorted.

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ' ', -1) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

Output:

```
id  name    created_at
3   name 66 2017-05-24
4   name 44 2017-05-25
2   name 2  2017-05-22
1   name 1  2017-05-20
```

Comment: what is minus one '-1'?

Comment: minus 1  means that `SUBSTRING_INDEX` will return all characters to the right of the last space (`' '`)

Comment: nice exactly that i need. tnx

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple trick to do this, that is to order by length first, then by name. Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
ORDER BY LENGTH(name) DESC, name DESC
```

Here's an example of this in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/49a335/3)

**Edit**: Please note, his will only work if your string is consistent as it is in your example data.

Answer (score 0):

Following query extracts number in name column with substring function and then order it accordingly.

```
SELECT *
FROM Orders
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(name, length('name')+2 , 3) AS UNSIGNED) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If `'name'` is not the same on each row, then you can do:

```
order by substring_index(name, ' ', 1),
         substring_index(name, ' ', -1) + 0
```

This will work if you have values such as:

```
a 1
a 2
a 10
b 1
b 100
```

(and of course if all start with "name" as well)